# Linear algebra problem: can a transformation be found to bring two vectors together?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's say we have two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, and two orthogonal transformations $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ ($\mathbf{A^T A = B^T B = I}$). 
Let $G=\langle \mathbf{A, B} \rangle$ be the group of transformations generated by $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.
Can one determine (preferably in an efficient way) if $\exists \mathbf{C} \in G$ s.t. $\vec{v} = \mathbf{C} \vec{u}$?

Put another way, does there exist some string of A's and B's that transform $\vec{u}$ into $\vec{v}$?

I should mention that I'm not confined to 3 dimensions or anything. N dimensional.

Comment: Presumably $\|u\|=\|v\|$. In ${\rm SO}(3)$, there is a copy of the free group $F_2$. This is used in proving the Banach-Tarski paradox, for example, so we can expect the orbit of $\langle A,B\rangle$ to be really wild in general.

Comment: I think that depends on $A$ and $B$. For example, say $u = (1,0,0), v=(0,0,1)$ and $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal transformations acting only on the first two  entries, say $A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta& 0\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and something similar for $B$. Then there would be no way to transform $u$ to $v$ using only $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes, I realize that sometimes it is possible and sometimes it is not.  I'm just wondering if there's a way (and efficient, hopefully polynomial in the dimension N) to determine if it's possible.  @anon, yes, clearly $|u|$ must equal $|v|$. The orbit can be wild, eh?

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the question. Are you asking for an algorithm? Then the input data should be given in a computer-friendly form, say, matrices $A, B$ should have coefficients in a specific number field and the same for $u, v$. If you are asking for computations over the reals, you should specify the computability model since there is no standard one.

Comment: If you want to work with some number-field but allow for more generators than 2 (say, 100, although this is an overkill), then this problem is undecidable already for subgroups of $SO(6)$.